# display announcements in user's dashboards per user type using codeigniter

Tags: php, html, css, database, codeigniter

I would like to display announcements in the different user's dashboards. What I am trying to do is to display it in the dashboard in which the user can close the announcement in the dashboard permanently, but what happens is that when a certain user close the announcement tab in the dashboard, all of the announcement in the same user type is being deleted. So can you please help me to figure out what approach should I use? Thanks!

## VIEW

```
 <div class="clearfix"></div>
          <?php 
            if($announcements = $this->Bid_Model->fetchItems('announcements')):
            foreach ($announcements as $announce): 
              if($announce->user_type == 6){?>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

              <div class="x_panel">
                <div class="x_title">
                  <h2>Announcement</h2>
                  <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                    <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="<?=base_url()?>Admin/deleteAnnouncement/<?=$announce->announcement_id?>" class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="x_content">

                <img src="<?php echo base_url().'uploads/';?>announcements/<?=$announce->image;?>" height="500" width="700">

                <h4><?=$announce->title?></h4>
                <h4><?=$announce->content?></h4>


                <div class="ln_solid"></div>
                  <!-- modals -->

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
             <?php } endforeach; endif; ?>
                  <!-- /modals -->
          <br />
```

## CONTROLLER

```
public function announceSubmit(){
        $this->session->userdata('user_data');
        $id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $title = $this->input->post('title', true);
        $users = $this->input->post('users', true);
        $content = $this->input->post('descr', true);

        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/announcements/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['max_size'] = '25000';


        $this->load->library('upload',$config);

            if(!$this->upload->do_upload('image-source')){
                print_r($this->upload->display_errors());
            }else{

                $announce_image = $this->upload->data('file_name');

                $data = array(
                    'title' => $title,
                    'user_type' => $users,
                    'content' => $content,
                    'image' => $announce_image,
                    'user_id' => $id
                ); 

                $this->Bid_Model->insertItem('announcements', $data);
                redirect('dashboard');
            }
        }

        public function deleteAnnouncement(){
            $this->Bid_Model->updateItem('announcements',['user_type' => 0],['announcement_id'=>$this->uri->segment(3)]);
            redirect('dashboard');
        }
```

## MODEL

```
function insertItem($table, $data = NULL){
        $this->db->insert($table, $data);
    }

    function insertItems($table,$data = array()){
        $this->db->insert_batch($table, $data);
    }


    function updateItem($table, $data, $var = NULL){
        if($var != NULL){
            $this->db->where($var);
        }
        $this->db->update($table, $data);
    }
```

Comment: I think [If possible] you need to add one more where clause with user_id too

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are storing your user related data in session so
**Controller :**

```
public function deleteAnnouncement() {
        $this->Bid_Model->updateItem('announcements', ['user_type' => 0], ['announcement_id' => $this->uri->segment(3), 'user_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id')]);
        redirect('dashboard');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, You are passing 2nd and 3rd parameters to `updateItem()` in the model as an array.

So it is better to do like this `$var = array()` rather than `$var = NULL`

Second, you are deleting announcements for a particular user so use user id to delete for only one user

`$id = $this->session->userdata('user_id')`

```
function updateItem($table, $data, $var = array()){
    $id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    if(count($var) > 0){
        $this->db->where($var);
    }
    $this->db->where('user_id', $id);
    $this->db->update($table, $data);
}
```

Comment: I already did what you told me but it's still not working. I think it is because I do not have any column for the user_id in my announcements table. Do you have any idea on how to pass all of the user's id upon submitting the form to create the announcement? I

Comment: @Jephte for an answer I have a question that who is creating announcements? user or admin?

Comment: It's the admin who creates the announcement @danish ali

Comment: @Jephte two options in my mind as I don't know the whole flow of your project/task. If the announcement is for one particular user then add user id in it. If it is for more than one user then use all IDs of these students